# How to get start date and end date of each week by providing only the year as input parameter in php?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a requirement where if I only pass the current year to a function then it should return all the start date and end date of all weeks of that year.
I want this functionality in Laravel.

I have tried a code which I got online but I am not getting how to use it according to my requirement

```
   <?php        
    $var=2019;
    $date=Carbon::now();
    $date->setISODate($var,52);
    echo $date->startOfWeek();
    echo"<br>";
    echo $date->endOfWeek();
    ?>
```

I want something like this:(For current year)
Week no 1: 2018-12-31 to 2019-01-06

Comment: Did you check the docs on setISODate?  Wouldn't you want 1 instead of 52?

Comment: Yeah I know it should be 1 but then it gives output only for that particular week which is 1

Comment: Do you know how to create a loop?

Comment: Yes but I don't know much as I am new to php

Comment: I recommend reading the PHP manual regarding loops and iterations then.  Learning the basic syntax should come first.

Comment: I know that I can use a for loop but I am not able to implement it over here

Comment: What do you mean by not able to implement it?

Comment: Just to put you on track: start by reading the doc about [for](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php), [while](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) and [do-while](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) control structures

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
$var=2019;
$date=Carbon::now();
$i=1;
for($i; $i<=52; $i++){
  $date->setISODate($var,$i);
echo $date->startOfWeek();
echo"<br>";
echo $date->endOfWeek();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A php generic solution using the `DateTime` and `DatePeriod` classes, for PHP 7+.

```
function getWeeksOf(int $year, bool $roundEdgeDates = false) : array
{
    $weeks = [];
    $yearStart = (new \DateTime("{$year}-01-01 00:00:00"));
    $yearEnd = (new \DateTime("{$year}-12-31 23:59:59"));

    $dateRange = new \DatePeriod(
        (clone $yearStart)->modify('Monday this week'), 
        new \DateInterval('P1W'), 
        (clone $yearEnd)->modify('Sunday this week')
    );

    foreach($dateRange as $date){
        $weeks[] = [
            'start' => $date,
            'end' => (clone $date)->modify('+6 days 23 hours 59 minutes 59 seconds')
        ];
    }

    if ($roundEdgeDates) {
        $weeks[0]['start'] = $yearStart;
        $weeks[count($weeks) - 1]['end'] = $yearEnd;
    }

    return $weeks;
}
```

You can see it running here [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfc3dec0a80efb2c2cc97d51b2e8bc338221296a)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getWeeks($year, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $weekDates = [];

    // Get start of a year
    $start = Carbon::createFromDate($year)->startOfYear();

    // Skip week if the first day of week is in previous year
    // Uncomment next 2 lines if you want skip 2018 and get only weeks in 2019 :)
    // if($start->startOfWeek()->year != $year)
        // $start->addWeek();

    while($start->year == $year){
        $weekDates[] = [
            'start' => $start->startOfWeek()->format($format),
            'end' => $start->endOfWeek()->format($format)
        ];
        $start->addWeek();
    }

    return $weekDates;
}

dd(getWeeks(2019));
```